# Sql group by different set in same select query

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have the table in the following format

```
reporting_date  interest_payment  balance
200401          5                   10
200401          10                  20
200403          25                  25
200403          15                  10
200406          5                   10
200407          20                  10
200407          25                  5
```

I would like to group different column in  a bit different on the basis of reporting_date so that my out put looks like this

```
 reporting_date  interest_payment  balance
    200401          15                10
    200403          40                25
    200406          5                 10
    200407          45                10
```

i.e the interest_payment should grouped by reporting date but while grouping the balance i want to group by first row of that reporting date only

so for 200401 the interest payment will be 15 but for balance will be only 10

```
select sum(interest_payment),sum(balance)
from table
group by reporting_date
```

This is the query i was planning to use but obviously it will not work for balance column .Is there a way to handle this in sql server so that in a single query i can group by particular set but for the other i can group by different set.

Thanks.

Comment: What gives precedence to balance of 10 over balance of 20 in the first two records?

Comment: i want to select the first balance field in the grouping set

Comment: What defines *first*? The order of appearance on the screen is not a criterion a sql query could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following query:

```
SELECT reporting_date, balance, (SELECT SUM(interest_payment)
                                 FROM #mytable 
                                 WHERE reporting_date = t.reporting_date
                                 GROUP BY reporting_date) AS sum_of_interest
FROM (
   SELECT reporting_date, balance,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY reporting_date ORDER BY id) AS rn
   FROM #mytable ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

I make the assumption that `id` field defines precedence for `balance`, i.e. the `balance` with the lowest related `id` value comes first.

Comment: so i have ten column to aggregate out of which 1 requires a different logic than the other nine ,would i use  SELECT SUM(interest_payment)
                                 FROM #mytable 
                                 WHERE reporting_date = t.reporting_date
                                 GROUP BY reporting_date) AS sum_of_interest for the rest of the 9 columns

Comment: how do i modify this query if i have 5 more interest_payment 1 ,interest_payment 2 .... interest_payment5 alnogwith balance column  to group by

Comment: This query requires a double scan of table rows. My version is less expensive and executed in a single pass.

Answer (score 0):

```
with t as (
    select 
        reporting_date, 
        interest_payment,
        first_value(balance) over (partition by reporting_date order by reporting_date) as b
    from table
)
select reporting_date, sum(interest_payment), min(b) 
from t 
group by reporting_date
```